# ADFS signout returns 404

Tags: identityserver3

We have a federation where ADFS3 is our main sign on mechanism with Identityserver as a relying party which is handling our Oauth. So when a user logs in we are redirected via the idserver to ADFS where they login, then we are redirected back and the user now has an oauth token issued by identityserver.

We are having issues with logoff when it is initiated by ADFS. Using fiddler I can see ADFS is redirecting to https://idserver/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 but this is returning a 404.

Is this the right URL its calling?
Have we missed something when creating the idserver?
I don't have a callbackpath configured so assume it should pick this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Katana Ws-Fed middleware from Microsoft doesn't support signout. You will have to implement this yourself -- middleware seems like an obvious approach.

Comment: OK thanks, did wonder. Don't suppose you have a link to a nice example?

Comment: Found this... [Federated Logout with the Katana WS-Federation Middleware](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/08/federated-logout-with-the-katana-ws-federation-middleware/)